# Pcolormesh value not mapped to correct bin in matplotlib BoundaryNorm

Tags: python, plot, colorbar

I'm plotting a single row of data using pcolormesh to provide color coding for statistical test output alongisde a timeseries.

I use a discretized colormap, and with the the correct number of colors versus bins in boundarynorm, I'm seeing that the values I'm trying to plot are not being mapped to the correct color. For example, the third data point and bar has the value 94, but is taking the color mapped between 95 and 97.5. Example below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl



# bbox
cb_x0 = 0.95
cb_y0 = 0.1225
cb_xlen = 0.05
cb_ylen = 0.205


cmap_whole = plt.cm.get_cmap('YlOrRd')
cmap0 = 'white'
cmap1 = cmap_whole(0.1)
cmap2 = cmap_whole(0.2)
cmap3 = cmap_whole(0.4)
cmap4 = cmap_whole(0.6)
cmap5 = cmap_whole(0.9)
colors = [cmap0,cmap1,cmap2,cmap3,cmap4,cmap5]
cmap_cl = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(colors, N=len(colors))
values = [85,90,92.5,95,97.5,99,100]

# coordinates and data
x = np.arange(1985,2020,3)
y = np.arange(0,2,1)
data = [17.0, 99.0, 94.0, 98.0, 82.0, 99.0, 99.0, 45.0, 55.0, 57.0, 94.0]


# plotting
f,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1)

h = ax.pcolormesh(x,y,np.reshape(data,(1,len(data))), cmap = cmap_cl, vmin = 85, vmax = 100) 
ax.tick_params(left=False,labelleft=False,bottom=True,labelbottom=False)

norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(values,6,clip=True)
cbax = f.add_axes([cb_x0, cb_y0, cb_xlen, cb_ylen])
cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax=cbax, cmap=cmap_cl,
                                   norm=norm,
                                   spacing='proportional',
                                   orientation='vertical',
                                   boundaries=values,
                                   extend='neither',
                                   ticks=values)
cb.ax.tick_params(labelcolor='0.2', labelsize=7, color='k', width=0.5, direction='out'); 
cb.ax.set_yticklabels(['0%','90%',None,'95%',None,None,'100%']) 
cb.outline.set_linewidth(0.6)

plt.show(h)
```

[here is my figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mll4I.png)

Comment: I think you need to provide the norm to pcolormesh as well.